# JWT token invalid, but why

Tags: javascript, authorization

I'm doing one of my first exercises on authorization, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with this one. I'm trying to validate the JWT token, but it gives me back that it's invalid

I get the token with httpie:

```
http POST :4000/auth/login email=test@test.com password=test
```

And then I try validating with httpie:

```
http GET :4000/images authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTY0ODgyMDI3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4ODI3NDcwfQ.AhArOvQTaJ7ohbPiyGiGTK5pFMWqjbZ5Kj9q2hXEhXU"
```

Which gives me: Invalid JWT token

This is my router/images.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const Image = require("../models").image;
const router = new Router();
const toData = require("../auth/jwt");

router.get("/images", async (req, res) => {
  const auth =
    req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
  if (auth && auth[0] === "Bearer" && auth[1]) {
    try {
      const data = toData(auth[1]);
      const allImages = await Image.findAll();
      res.send(allImages);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send("Invalid JWT token");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: "Please supply valid credentials" });
  }
});
```

This is the router/auth.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const { toJWT, toData } = require("../auth/jwt");

const router = new Router();

router.post("/auth/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).send("Email and password required");
    } else {
      res.send({ jwt: toJWT({ userId: 1 }) });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    next(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the auth/jwt.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const secret =
  process.env.JWT_SECRET || "e9rp^&^*&@9sejg)DSUA)jpfds8394jdsfn,m";

const toJWT = (data) => {
  return jwt.sign(data, secret, { expiresIn: "2h" });
};

const toData = (token) => {
  return jwt.verify(token, secret);
};

module.exports = { toJWT, toData };
```

Hope somebody can help :)

Comment: Have you tried to just finish after validating the token (maybe return the user id or something), the try catch block encloses the image operations as well, so it might actually be an error happening there. Also maybe output the error that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your router/images.js file, it looks like you are not requiring the toData method correctly. You are requiring the module with two exported functions, so if you use destructuruing, you would have to access your toData method like you did inside of auth.js.

Change line 4 of router/images.js to:

```
const { toData }  = require("../auth/jwt");
```

When you require the auth/jwt file with a single const that is not destructured, you would access the exported methods of that file with dot notation:

```
const jwt = require("../auth/jwt");

jwt.toData(auth[0]);
```

Comment: Yes! Awesome, thank you :) The subtleties in coding are impressive

Comment: Yes, they are! Glad it helped and your code is working as expected now. :)